# $ 5r + 4s + 3t + 6u = 100, \:\: r \ge s \ge t \ge u \ge 0 $ maximum and minimum possible of $r + s + t + u$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

We have
$$ 5r + 4s + 3t + 6u = 100, \:\: r \ge s \ge t \ge u \ge 0 $$
What is the sum of the maximum and minimum possible  of $r + s + t + u$?

---

**Attempt:**

Assume that $r'+s'+t'+u'$ is the maximum. Now if $u > 0$, then we can have
$$ (r' + K) + s' + t' + (u' - \frac{5}{6} K),  \:\: K > 0 $$ 
is bigger than the claimed maximum, with ($r=r'+K, s=s', t=t', u = u' - \frac{5}{6}K$). We have a contradiction. So $u'=0$.

Now see
$$ 5r + 4s + 3t = 100 $$

Similarly, let $r^{*} + s^{*} + u^{*}$ maximum. Then

$$ r^{*} + (s^{*} - \frac{3}{4}C) + (t^{*} + C),  \:\: C > 0 $$

is bigger then the claimed maximum, provided that $s = s^{*} -(3/4)C \ge t = t^{*} + C$
with 
$$ C \le \frac{4}{7}(s^{*}-t^{*})$$

After this I have no idea.

---

Comment: Are $r,s,t,u$ integers or real number?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We get $$20\le r+s+t+u\le 25$$, where the minum will be attained for $$r=20,s=t=u=0$$ and the maximum by $$r=s=t=\frac{25}{3},u=0$$

Comment: Wow! Jesus Christ xD xD, dude how did you find that $20 \le r+s+t+u \le 25$ ? That is so awsome, i was sweating my a** off to find the answer, how did you get to that conclusion? Can you please shed some light

Comment: My calculations are some sheets of papers Long!

Comment: @K.K.McDonald it's possible to think about it geometrically. For example in 2D condition, you are trying to maximize the distance from origin of a equally inclined line. In 3D, you are trying to maximize the distance from Origin of a equally inclined plane. But the catch it that you need to do it with respect to the given constraints. Think about it in 2D and 3D, you will get it in 4D as well.

Comment: xD xD, Well if this problem was a Kaiju, you were a Class-S hero and i was Class-C (with a little help). That solution of yours were stylish and neato. The geometrical interpretation was also nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Just to elaborate on one of the bounds in @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer**. Using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chebyshev%27s_Inequality), because $5>4>3$ and $r\geq s \geq t$
$$100=5r + 4s + 3t + 6u\geq \frac{5+4+3}{3}\cdot(r+s+t) + 6u=\\
4\cdot(r+s+t) + 6u\geq 
4\cdot(r+s+t) + 4u$$
and $$r+s+t+u\leq 25$$

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i got the constraints wrong. In second attempt, we introduce the slack variables $a,b,c \ge 0$, where $u \ge 0, t = u+a \ge u, s= t+b \ge t, r = s+c \ge s$. Now we reformulate the problem. We have:
$$\max (4u+3a+2b+c)$$
$$\text{subject to }\quad 18u+12a+9b+5c = 100 ,\quad a,b,c,u\ge0$$

now we replace the constraint into the objective $c = \frac{100-18u-12a-9b}{5} \ge 0$ and thus $\max (4u+3a+2b+\frac{100-18u-12a-9b}{5}) = \max(\frac{100+2u-12a+b}{5})$. Since this i linear program and the line is monotone, so the max or min is at the end or beginning of the intervals. we consider extreme cases. since $c \ge 0$ one of these cases must be the solution $(b = 100/9 , a=c=u=0)$ or $(b = 0, a=100/12,c=u=0)$ or $(b=a=0 ,c=100/5,u=0)$ or $(b =a=c=0 , u=100/18)$. By inspection we get $(b = 0, a=100/12,c=u=0)$ is indeed the f***ing solution which is equal to $\frac{100+100/4}{5}=25$.

Now back for the minimum, we have
$$\min (4u+3a+2b+c)$$
$$\text{subject to }\quad 18u+12a+9b+5c = 100 ,\quad a,b,c,u\ge0$$

by the same chain of reasoning we get that in this case $(b=a=0 ,c=100/5,u=0)$ is our fortunate candidate and the answer is $c=100/5=20$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my answer, thnks to Dr.Sonhard's hint.

If
$$  s^{*}  > t^{*} $$
then there is C such that $r^{*},s^{*},t^{*}$ does not sum to maximum. So it must be that $s^{*}=t^{*}$.

Now we have 
$$ 5r^{*} +7s^{*}=100 $$

Similarly,
$$  (r^{*} + C) + (s^{*} - (5/7) C) $$
Will be bigger than the claimed. 
With
$$ C \ge (7/12)(s^{*}-r^{*}) $$
Thus we must have also $r^{*}=s^{*}$.

So the solution is $r=s=t=25/3$, for the maximum case.